# HIve query stops in between when running MapReduce job

Tags: hadoop, hive

I am running a single node cluster on Ubuntu 16.04. Hadoop version is 2.7.2 and Hive 1.2.1.

When I run **hive queries which involve map-reduce job like partitioning** **or bucketing** etc. It shows progress for sometime and then process get stop and comes out of command line. **All the daemons get stop automatically and even my hadoop user (hduser) closes down and command line comes to default user.**

Here is my log when I run query of copying data from one table to other.

```
hive> insert into table A1 select id,age,symptoms_pertaining_illness,sex from allcities;
Query ID = hduser_20160723195334_b34925b4-d6b7-46f2-a5ef-2e9e6b7c5293
Total jobs = 3
Launching Job 1 out of 3
Number of reduce tasks is set to 0 since there's no reduce operator
Starting Job = job_1469283576772_0001, Tracking URL = http://gaurav-HP-Notebook:8088/proxy/application_1469283576772_0001/
Kill Command = /usr/local/hadoop/bin/hadoop job  -kill job_1469283576772_0001
Hadoop job information for Stage-1: number of mappers: 3; number of reducers: 0
2016-07-23 19:53:43,738 Stage-1 map = 0%,  reduce = 0%
2016-07-23 19:53:58,136 Stage-1 map = 33%,  reduce = 0%, Cumulative CPU 18.15 sec
killing job with: job_1469283576772_0001
gaurav@gaurav-HP-Notebook:~$
```

I tried setting up no. of mappers and reducers but it didn't work.
The problem is coming with smaller as well as larger datasets.

Comment: That's the Hive log, it's just scratching the surface. Look into the YARN log for that `job_1469283576772_0001` (but mind the legacy "job" prefix, YARN uses "application") e.g. `yarn logs -applicationId application_1469283576772_0001`

Comment: When I ran command  > 'yarn logs -applicationId application_1469283576772_0001'  the output is  > '16/07/24 19:19:57 INFO client.RMProxy: Connecting to ResourceManager at localhost/127.0.0.1:8050
16/07/24 19:19:57 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
Unable to get ApplicationState. Attempting to fetch logs directly from the filesystem.
/tmp/logs/hduser/logs/application_1469361836698_0001 does not exist.
Log aggregation has not completed or is not enabled.'

Comment: What about `yarn application -status application_1469283576772_0001` -- did the job start running *(then the log was lost because you don't have Log Aggregation enabled)* or did it fail to start altogether *(and Aggregation had nothing to aggregate anyway)*?

Comment: [Samson](http://stackoverflow.com/users/5162372/samson-scharfrichter) we (i, user6275041 and many of my classmates have same problem). I directly logs into hduser and then ran the querry and after some evereything stops and it comes out to user login screen. When i log in again i have to restart daemons and i have to run safemode leave command then only my hive run but the problem still persists. I am wondering I have i3 processor and 8 gb ram, and [He](http://stackoverflow.com/users/6275041/user6275041) has i7 -8gb and we both run on ubuntu. But our tutor has i5 with virtal environment.

Comment: And the querries runs successfully in his system. I have Log Aggregation enabled by [This](https://amalgjose.com/2015/08/01/enabling-log-aggregation-in-yarn/) Tutorial but no affect. When I run command 'yarn application -status application_1469283576772_0001' the output is 'Application with id 'application_1469283576772_0001' doesn't exist in RM or Timeline Server.'

Comment: Ok Somehow.  When I run command 'yarn logs -applicationId application_1469420347957_0001' it is showing very large log. Its Impossible to paste here so how can i show it to you cause i am not getting anything out of it.

Comment: [Output](http://www.filehosting.org/file/details/588222/xyz.txt) of 'yarn logs -applicationId application_1469420347957_0001'